# Allowing access to USB device dialog when in Lock Task Mode

Tags: android

I'm using device owner to run the app in lock task mode. However, when the app requests access to the USB device, the permission dialog is never shown.

After disabling lock task mode, the access request dialog appears as expected.

Ideally I would like to just be able to show the dialog whilst in lock task mode, or somehow just permamently enable access to all USB devices?

I'm aware there's the [app whitelist](https://developer.android.com/work/dpc/dedicated-devices/lock-task-mode#whitelist_apps) for lock task mode, but I have no idea what app name for the USB access dialog would come under, if it even has one.

I have **not** set the DISALLOW_CREATE_WINDOWS user restriction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Need to add `com.android.systemui` to the lock task mode whitelist

```
dpm.setLockTaskPackages(adminName, new String[]{mContext.getPackageName(), "com.android.systemui"});
```

Answer (score -1):

Put this package in your whitelist:
"com.samsung.android.MtpApplication"

Comment: This is for media transfer?