# Allowing access to USB debugging authorization dialog when in Lock Task Mode

Tags: android, adb

I'm using device owner to run an app in lock task mode.

However, when I connect a PC with adb, the USB Debugging Authorization permission dialog is never shown.After disabling lock task mode, the access request dialog appears as expected.

[image: USB Debugging Authorization dialog]

If I connect a PC that is already authorized its possible to use adb.

I'm aware there's the app whitelist for lock task mode, but I have no idea what package name for the USB Debugging Authorization permission would come under.

```
String[] whitelist = new String[]{getPackageName(),"com.android.systemui"};
mDevicePolicyManager.setLockTaskPackages(mAdminComponentName,active ? whitelist : new String[]{});
```

This question is very similar to [Allowing access to USB device dialog when in Lock Task Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56379976/allowing-access-to-usb-device-dialog-when-in-lock-task-mode)
 and I've tried it - it works for other types of USB devices but not USB Debugging.

Comment: N.B. `adb shell dumpsys window` can tell you which package the windows on screen belong to.

Comment: That's an awesome tip! Thanx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the source code in [com.android.systemui.usb](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/1fc831d5780d831e2fc2766c7b6ff126eede4c55:frameworks/base/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/usb/UsbDebuggingActivity.java)

```
String[] whitelist = new String[]{getPackageName(),"com.android.systemui.usb"};
mDevicePolicyManager.setLockTaskPackages(mAdminComponentName, whitelist);
```